# SPAC: FTCV -> eToro: What may become of my FTCV shares post merger?

Tags: stocks, shares, warrants, spac

After yesterday's [announcement](https://www.etoro.com/wp-content/uploads/investors/eToro-Press-Release.pdf) that eToro and [FTCV](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/FTCV:NASDAQ) are planning on merging, FTCV shares [became available](https://www.etoro.com/markets/ftcv) to eToro users. Target for the merger of the SPAC and eToro will be Q3 2021.

Opening a position in FTCV now, what will happen to the shares post merger?

- Could they lose value given that FTCV only owns 9% following the business combination?
- Will current shareholders of FTCV stock retain their stock post
  merger?
- Will it only be a ticker change?
- Do owners of FTCV stock
  bought on eToro have a Warrant to buy stock at a fixed price post
  merger?

Scenario (hypothetical):

- 500 FTCV shares bought on eToro today at USD 13.00 per unit
- Share price right before merger would be 20.00 per unit

-> What could happen to the shares post merger?